# Moving image to right or left side of set of images onClick

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to do this so that when the frog at the bottom of the page is clicked, it will go to the opposite side of the images it is next to each time. So far I've been able to do it once, but I can't figure out how to do it more past these 2 methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I removed some personal info if you're wondering why some stuff is missing.)

```
<html>

<head>
<title>
    Assignment 4
</title>
<script>
    function AlertStudent() {
        alert("");
    }

    function ConsoleStudent() {
        console.log("");
    }

    function ShowStudent() {
        var x = document.getElementById("student");
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

    function HideStudent() {
        var x = document.getElementById("student");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    function AlertSubject() {
        alert("");
    }

    function ConsoleSubject() {
        console.log("");
    }

    function ShowSubject() {
        var x = document.getElementById("subject");
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

    function HideSubject() {
        var x = document.getElementById("subject");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    function AlertAssignment() {
        alert("Assignment 4 - 14th September 2019");
    }

    function ConsoleAssignment() {
        console.log("Assignment 4 - 14th September 2019");
    }

    function ShowAssignment() {
        var x = document.getElementById("assignment");
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

    function HideAssignment() {
        var x = document.getElementById("assignment");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    function AlertLab() {
        alert("Wednesday 8:30-10:30");
    }

    function ConsoleLab() {
        console.log("Wednesday 8:30-10:30");
    }

    function ShowLab() {
        var x = document.getElementById("lab");
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

    function HideLab() {
        var x = document.getElementById("lab");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    function SwitchParagraphs() {
        var p1Text = p1.textContent;
        p1.textContent = p2.textContent;
        p2.textContent = p1Text;
    }

    function Cat() {
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "User clicks Cat";

        var displaySpan = document.getElementById("display");
        displaySpan.innerHTML = "Cat is clicked";

        var image = document.getElementById("displayImg");
        image.src = "cat.png";
    }

    function Dog() {
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "User clicks Dog";

        var displaySpan = document.getElementById("display");
        displaySpan.innerHTML = "Dog is clicked";

        var image = document.getElementById("displayImg");
        image.src = "dog.png";
    }

    function Frog() {
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "User clicks Frog";

        var displaySpan = document.getElementById("display");
        displaySpan.innerHTML = "Frog is clicked";

        var image = document.getElementById("displayImg");
        image.src = "frog.png";
    }

    var counter = 0;
    var counter1 = 0;

    function Hour() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterHour");
        counterSpan.innerHTML = counter;
        if (counter >= 23) {
            counter = -1;
        }
    }

    function Minute() {
        counter1 = counter1 + 1;
        var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterMinute");
        counterSpan.innerHTML = counter1;
        if (counter1 >= 59) {
            counter1 = -1;
        }
    }

    function AlertAnimal() {
        alert("Don’t click me, click the frog");
    }

    function FrogChange() {
        var image = document.getElementById("displayImg1");
        image.src = "frog.png";

        var x = document.getElementById("frog");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    function FrogClick2() {
        var image = document.getElementById("displayImg3");
        image.src = "frog.png";
        var x = document.getElementById("displayImg1");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="student"></div>
<button onClick="ShowStudent()">Show</button>
<button onClick="HideStudent()">Hide</button>
<button onClick="AlertStudent()">Alert</button>
<button onClick="ConsoleStudent()">Console</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="subject"></div>
<button onClick="ShowSubject()">Show</button>
<button onClick="HideSubject()">Hide</button>
<button onClick="AlertSubject()">Alert</button>
<button onClick="ConsoleSubject()">Console</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="assignment">Assignment 4 - 14th September 2019</div>
<button onClick="ShowAssignment()">Show</button>
<button onClick="HideAssignment()">Hide</button>
<button onClick="AlertAssignment()">Alert</button>
<button onClick="ConsoleAssignment()">Console</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="lab">Wednesday 8:30-10:30</div>
<button onClick="ShowLab()">Show</button>
<button onClick="HideLab()">Hide</button>
<button onClick="AlertLab()">Alert</button>
<button onClick="ConsoleLab()">Console</button>
<br>
<br>
<hr />
<p id="p1"></p>
<button onClick="SwitchParagraphs()">Switch Paragraphs</button>
<p id="p2"></p>
<hr />
<button onClick="Cat()">Cat</button>
<button onClick="Dog()">Dog</button>
<button onClick="Frog()">Frog</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="myText" />
<br>
<br>
<span id="display"></span>
<br>
<br>
<img id="displayImg" />
<hr />
<button onClick="Hour()">Hour</button>
<font size="7">
<span id="counterHour">0</span>:<span id="counterMinute">0</span></font>
<button onClick="Minute()">Minute</button>
<hr />
<img id="displayImg1" onClick="FrogClick2()" /><img id="displayImg2" />
<img src="cat.png" ; onClick="AlertAnimal()" ; id="cat" /><img 
 src="dog.png" ; id="dog" ; onClick="AlertAnimal()" ;/>
<img src="frog.png" ; onClick="FrogChange()" ; id="frog" /><img id="displayImg3" onClick="FrogFlick3()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using different javascript functions to move frog about, use only one.  Supply the current element where the frog is by using 'this' in the function parameter.

```
        <script>
        function AlertStudent() {
            alert("");
        }

        function ConsoleStudent() {
            console.log("");
        }

        function ShowStudent() {
            var x = document.getElementById("student");
            x.style.display = "block";
        }

        function HideStudent() {
            var x = document.getElementById("student");
            x.style.display = "none";
        }

        function AlertSubject() {
            alert("");
        }

        function ConsoleSubject() {
            console.log("");
        }

        function ShowSubject() {
            var x = document.getElementById("subject");
            x.style.display = "block";
        }

        function HideSubject() {
            var x = document.getElementById("subject");
            x.style.display = "none";
        }

        function AlertAssignment() {
            alert("Assignment 4 - 14th September 2019");
        }

        function ConsoleAssignment() {
            console.log("Assignment 4 - 14th September 2019");
        }

        function ShowAssignment() {
            var x = document.getElementById("assignment");
            x.style.display = "block";
        }

        function HideAssignment() {
            var x = document.getElementById("assignment");
            x.style.display = "none";
        }

        function AlertLab() {
            alert("Wednesday 8:30-10:30");
        }

        function ConsoleLab() {
            console.log("Wednesday 8:30-10:30");
        }

        function ShowLab() {
            var x = document.getElementById("lab");
            x.style.display = "block";
        }

        function HideLab() {
            var x = document.getElementById("lab");
            x.style.display = "none";
        }

        function SwitchParagraphs() {
            var p1Text = p1.textContent;
            p1.textContent = p2.textContent;
            p2.textContent = p1Text;
        }

        function Cat() {
            document.getElementById("myText").value = "User clicks Cat";

            var displaySpan = document.getElementById("display");
            displaySpan.innerHTML = "Cat is clicked";

            var image = document.getElementById("displayImg");
            image.src = "cat.png";
        }

        function Dog() {
            document.getElementById("myText").value = "User clicks Dog";

            var displaySpan = document.getElementById("display");
            displaySpan.innerHTML = "Dog is clicked";

            var image = document.getElementById("displayImg");
            image.src = "dog.png";
        }

        function Frog() {
            document.getElementById("myText").value = "User clicks Frog";

            var displaySpan = document.getElementById("display");
            displaySpan.innerHTML = "Frog is clicked";

            var image = document.getElementById("displayImg");
            image.src = "frog.png";
        }

        var counter = 0;
        var counter1 = 0;

        function Hour() {
            counter = counter + 1;
            var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterHour");
            counterSpan.innerHTML = counter;
            if (counter >= 23) {
                counter = -1;
            }
        }

        function Minute() {
            counter1 = counter1 + 1;
            var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterMinute");
            counterSpan.innerHTML = counter1;
            if (counter1 >= 59) {
                counter1 = -1;
            }
        }

        function AlertAnimal() {
            alert("Don’t click me, click the frog");
        }

        function FrogChange(el) {
            console.log(el.id);
            if(el.id == "displayImg3" ){
                document.getElementById("displayImg3").src = "";
                document.getElementById("displayImg1").src = "frog.png";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("displayImg3").src = "frog.png";
                document.getElementById("displayImg1").src = "";            
            }

    //        var image = document.getElementById("displayImg1");
    //        image.src = "frog.png";
    //
    //        var x = document.getElementById("frog");
    //        x.style.display = "none";
        }

        function FrogClick2() {
            var image = document.getElementById("displayImg3");
            image.src = "frog.png";
            var x = document.getElementById("displayImg1");
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

        <div id="student"></div>
    <button onClick="ShowStudent()">Show</button>
    <button onClick="HideStudent()">Hide</button>
    <button onClick="AlertStudent()">Alert</button>
    <button onClick="ConsoleStudent()">Console</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="subject"></div>
    <button onClick="ShowSubject()">Show</button>
    <button onClick="HideSubject()">Hide</button>
    <button onClick="AlertSubject()">Alert</button>
    <button onClick="ConsoleSubject()">Console</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="assignment">Assignment 4 - 14th September 2019</div>
    <button onClick="ShowAssignment()">Show</button>
    <button onClick="HideAssignment()">Hide</button>
    <button onClick="AlertAssignment()">Alert</button>
    <button onClick="ConsoleAssignment()">Console</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="lab">Wednesday 8:30-10:30</div>
    <button onClick="ShowLab()">Show</button>
    <button onClick="HideLab()">Hide</button>
    <button onClick="AlertLab()">Alert</button>
    <button onClick="ConsoleLab()">Console</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr />
    <p id="p1"></p>
    <button onClick="SwitchParagraphs()">Switch Paragraphs</button>
    <p id="p2"></p>
    <hr />
    <button onClick="Cat()">Cat</button>
    <button onClick="Dog()">Dog</button>
    <button onClick="Frog()">Frog</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="myText" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img id="displayImg" />
    <hr />
    <button onClick="Hour()">Hour</button>
    <font size="7">
    <span id="counterHour">0</span>:<span id="counterMinute">0</span></font>
    <button onClick="Minute()">Minute</button>
    <hr />
    <img id="displayImg1" onClick="FrogChange(this)" />
    <img src="cat.png" onClick="AlertAnimal();" id="cat" />
    <img src="dog.png" id="dog" onClick="AlertAnimal();" />
    <img id="displayImg3" src="frog.png" onClick="FrogChange(this);" />
```